# Get city from lookup table

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have created and configured DB in : [MongoDB Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EpuPHJ5iiXH)

There are different roles for User collection. I want to get city: "address" for all the roles.

But there is a condition as for role : "doctor".

For doctor: city: "address" should be clinic address from **centers** collection.
If city address not present in **centers** collection, get city: "address" from **user** collection address.current_address.city if neither present default address should be "-".

For all other roles, fetch address from **users** collection, general.current_address.city, if address not present , default "-".

I am able to achieve as shown in **MongoDB Play** link but it's taking a long time for large dataset. Is there any way to optimize the query.

Please let me know if anyone needs any further details.

Comment: What about  embedding  the centers  in  the  user collection or viceversa ? Your initial lookup seems to be the bottleneck of the query but also alot of sequentials addFields which seems looping the collection every time  ...

Comment: Apart from embedding centers, what do you suggest to optimize this query?